How can I debug my broken desktop environment after updating to a newer Linux kernel?
I am using Ubuntu 24.04. I was previously using Linux kernel version 6.5, but I have installed kernel v6.8.0-31 from the linux-image-generic package available in the apt repository. My mousepad doesn't work on the new kernel.
How can I debug this problem?
On Linux 6.8, sudo lshw -C input shows five things, one of which is mouse related.
sudo lshw -C input
*-input:4
   product: TPPS/2 Synaptics TrackPoint
   physical id: 7
   logical name: input5
   logical name: /dev/input/event4
   logical name: /dev/input/mouse0
   capabilities: i8042

On Linux 6.5, there are about 14 devices, 3 of which are mouse-related.
*-input:2
    product: SYNA8017:00 06CB:CEB2 Touchpad
    physical id: 4
    logical name: dev/input/event5
    logical name: /dev/input/mouse1
    capabilities: i2c

*-input:4
   product: SYNA8017:00 05CB:CEB2 Mouse
   physical id: 10
   logical name: input9
   logical name: /dev/input/event4
   logical name: /dev/input/mouse0
   capabilities: i2c

Is there a driver that I can install to make this work?
Additionally, my screen resolution is stuck at 2880x1800, 16:10 resolution. This is very large and difficult to read. It appears to be stuck at that constant. How can I fix this?

Can you revert to the old kernel? Is there a specific reason you wanted to use this new kernel?

Ubuntu 24.04 does not provide any software via apt that is specific to the Linux 6.5 kernel version rather than 6.8, such as linux-tools-generic 6.5, perf, and other software. Additionally, Linux 6.5 is no longer officially supported and receiving security updates.

The bugs were in an earlier version of Linux 6.8.0, specifically 6.8.0-31. I have upgraded to Linux 6.8.0-41 and it resolved my most important problems.
